# Update UITableView every second

Tags: ios, uitableview, nstimer

I am wondering what is the proper way of showing countdown in fairly complex UITableViewCells, in each cell one countdown with different time.

I could have NSTimer for each cell separately but then the cells wouldnt update at same time. I could have one NSTimer for all cells but calling reloadData on uitableview is fairly expensive to do every second, isnt it?

Obviously the needs to be updated only in visible cells.

Any ideas, best practice, know how on this matter?

Comment: is Your requirement is Reload perticular cell ?

Comment: every visible cell ... and i dont even need to reload whole cell, just update one leabel in each visible cell

Comment: For Update Content in Cell you must need to Update cell that perticular cell Or whole Table, you cant update Any Content in cell without Update it.

Comment: Of course I can if I can get cells instance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some thoughts on how I would implement this:

- Create a custom class for the cell's prototype and implement an `update` method in that class. This method updates the label.
- Create the timer in the custom `TableViewController` class
- Whenever the timer fires, iterate through the cells via the `indexPath`. `UITableView.CellForRowAtIndexPath` returns `nil` for cells which aren't visible.
- Call the cell's `update` method for each of these visible cells.

Comment: sounds legit, will try

Comment: this guided me to use [UITableView visibleCells] method in combination with [UITableView indexPathForCell:] ... thanks

Comment: I used the same concept for CollectionView. Worked like a charm: `let visibleCells = self.collectionView.visibleCells`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach would be to use `NSNotificationCenter`.

- Your view controller would post a notification whenever your time period has elapsed.
- Each of your UITableViewCell would register for this notification and update its display in response.

Note that to prevent memory leaks you need to remove each UITableViewCell as an observer as it goes off-screen. This can easily be done in the `UITableViewDelegate`'s 
`tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method.

The advantage of doing this is that you don't need to subclass UITableViewCell nor to try and keep track of each cell that needs refreshing.

Comment: thanks, this solution sounds really clean ... however it is complex cell and i already have subclass of it with outlets from storyboard and some other logic specific just for the cell

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath, store a reference to each cell you need.

```
if (indexPath.row == indexPath1.row) {
    _timerCell1 = cell;
} else if (indexPath.row == indexPath2.row) {
    _timerCell2 = cell;
} ...
```

Schedule a timer to update each cell when that cell needs to be updated.

```
_timer1 = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCell1) userInfo:nil repeats:true];
_timer2 = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(updateCell2) userInfo:nil repeats:true];
```

This eliminates the need for any updates to the tableView.

Comment: thanks, but zisofts answer pointed me to the UITableViews api I needed for this so no extra work like storing references to UITableViewCells is needed

Answer (score -1):

```
From the image, it looks like your model is a set of actions the user plans to take. I would arrange things this way:

1) MyAction is an NSObject with a name and a due date. MyAction implements something like this:

- (NSString *)timeRemainingString {
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval secondsLeft = [self.dueDate timeIntervalSinceDate:now];
    // divide by 60, 3600, etc to make a pretty string with colons
    // just to get things going, for now, do something simple
    NSString *answer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"seconds left = %f", secondsLeft];
    return answer;
}
2) StatusViewController keeps a handle to the model which is an NSArray of MyActions, it also has an NSTimer (just one) that tells it time is passing.

// schedule timer on viewDidAppear
// invalidate on viewWillDisappear

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.model.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyAction *myAction = [self.model objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // this can be a custom cell.  to get it working at first,
    // maybe start with the default properties of a UITableViewCell

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [myAction timeRemainingString];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [myAction name];
}
```

Comment: as I said in my question, reloadData is too expensive to call every second